# Distinctions between "froisser," "plisser," "friper," and "plier"?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Both of the first two seem to translate as "crease" among other things, and that's not really a word we would say two different ways in English. Granted there's "fold" also in English, but there's definitely a distinction between "crease" and "fold," and in that case we are getting "plier" involved as well. And then there's *friper*.

What are the distinctions between the usage of those four words?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Froisser, c'est l'anglais *crumple* — faire une multitude de plis très irréguliers. Par exemple on peut "froisser du papier en boule". Si on défait la boule plus tard pour aplatir le papier, il sera toujours "froissé".

Plisser, c'est faire une multitude de plis suivant un motif régulier, comme l'anglais *pleat*. On peut parler d'une "robe plissée" par exemple, pour une robe dont le volant est fait de nombreux plis parallèles à intervalles réguliers, ou de plisser du papier "en éventail". Il y a aussi l'expression "plisser des yeux" qui signifie fermer les paupières à demi pour faire un effort de vision (anglais *squint*).

Plier, c'est faire *un* pli (anglais *fold*). Ce n'est d'ailleurs pas tout à fait pareil que l'anglais *crease*, qui serait "marquer le pli": on peut plier quelque chose de malléable, comme un trombone, sans pour autant marquer le pli. Marquer le pli avec du papier, c'est passer son doigt ou un objet en appuyant sur le pli. Quand on repasse un habit, on dit aussi "marquer le pli" quand on passe le fer au-dessus du pli. Pour ce qui est du nom anglais *crease*, il peut être rendu par "le pli" (par exemple, le pli de la jambe du pantalon)  ou bien, en particulier quand il a été déplié, "la marque du pli" (par exemple, une feuille de papier plate peut porter la marque d'un pli qu'on vient d'y faire).

Friper est proche de froisser, avec un peu moins le sens d'une déformation et plus le sens d'un changement de texture. Par exemple on peut dire que la peau d'un abricot se fripe en mûrissant, ce qui signifie qu'elle est moins tendue et que des rides y apparaissent. On peut parler d'un visage fripé, c'est-à-dire ridé. On peut friper un papier ou un tissu, après quoi il aura un relief mais restera à peu près plat. Par contre froisser du papier, c'est en faire des boules, ou autrement le déformer de sa forme plate originale.

Comment: Pour *plisser* donc peut-être "pleat". Quant à *plier*: What is the crease in a pant leg, the *pli*? And is that also *marquer le pli* when I iron them, even if I'm introducing one the fabric doesn't really have? Now say I fold a piece of paper in half and then run my thumb along the crease, pressing down to flatten it -- is that also a *pli* and am I *en train de marquer le pli* ?

Comment: @LukeSawczak yes, added these and a few more

Comment: Merci, ça fait maintenant une réponse très utile et complète !